# Cant Compile jar if added to a package

Tags: java, jar, package

Problem: I wrote a hello world java program, compiled and created a jar file of it - PERFECT, no problems there.

I now added the following to the top of the source code

```
package za.ac.uj.csc2a;
```

saved the code, place all the files in the right directories and every time i compile with this batch file

```
del *.class
del *.jar
del *.txt

echo compiling HelloWorld.java.....

javac HelloWorld.java

javap -c HelloWorld.class > ByteCode.txt

jar cfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class

java -jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld.jar
```

i get,

```
Error: Unable to acces jarfile za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld.jar
```

Any Advice....

---

Here is the final bat file that works

```
del *.class
del *.jar
del *.txt
RD /Q /S bin

echo compiling HelloWorld.java.....

MD bin

javac -d bin za/ac/uj/csc2a/HelloWorld.java
javap -c bin/za/ac/uj/csc2a/HelloWorld.class > ByteCode.txt
jar cfe HelloWorld.jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld -C bin .
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
pause
```

thanks alot

Aiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jar is named Helloworld.jar:

```
 jar cfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class
```

But you call it with the package name as prefix to the jar:

```
 java -jar za/ac/uj/csc2a/HelloWorld.jar

 java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

should be right.

Normally, you put your classes and sources in different directories, if you use packages. A typical tree looks like

```
proj
|-- src
|   |-- za
|       |-- ac
|           `-- HelloWorld.java
|-- bin
    |-- za
        |-- ac
            `-- HelloWorld.class
```

You can move to the src-directory, and compile with:

```
 javac -d ../bin za/ac/HelloWorld.java
```

(reduced the package/path length for convenience) This will produce the directory structure in `bin` if needed (or often `classes`)

Then, to jar the whole thing with the correct directory structure, you change to `proj`, and issue:

```
jar cfe HelloWorld.jar za.ac.HelloWorld -C bin .
```

The dot stands for the whole directory.

```
jar -help
```

will tell you more options. To create a runnable jar you need a manifest too. Else you can start your app:

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar za.ac.HelloWorld
```

(shortened the path a bit again).

Note, that the structure of the directory has to reflect the package declaration. You can't omit a part (`za`), and step into the next directory (`ac`). The class to run is za.ac.HelloWorld and therefor it is searched for in za/ac/ - no matter whether in the file system or in the jar.

If you learn to issue the commands from the right base, it is easy. If not, you'll get years of trial and error.

For a jar which can be startet with `java -jar`, you need a manifest. A template is generated by the jar command. There you add

```
Main-Class: za.ac.HelloWorld
```

with a following blank line. Again: the whole name with package is needed. `Main-Class` can't be written as Mainclass. HelloWorld must not be followed by .class or .java - common mistakes! But as you know, you may use the -e switch to specify the main class, but again: Include the package name.

Comment: It doesn't seem like he has a manifest file though, so starting it with `-jar` may not work as expected.

Comment: That is another problem, indeed.

Comment: @aioobe, the jar tool creates a default manifest with no Main-Class. adding the e switch allows you to set a entry point for the jar, thus according to user unknwn my statement for jarring should look like this>

jar cfe HelloWorld.jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld -C bin

Comment: @userunknown Your first impressions are right - i want to be able to run a jar file as stated above the use of the jar tools creates a default manifest with no Main-Class, adding the e switch allows you to set a entry point for the jar file.

But upon your above help, there seems to be no -D switch, when i run the batch file javac gives a list of switches and -D is not there

Comment: @userunknown: I understand what you said: and you are correct, unfortunatly i could not get it right through the cmd prompt, and did it manually, 

`    HelloWorld.class INSIDE jar za.ac.uj.csc2a

Thank you for all your help, ill work on the cmdline thing

Aiden

Comment: @AidenStrydom: a) aioobe critizized before I corrected my post the first time. b) Oh - is this handy -e switch new? I updated my post accordingly. c) The -D switch has to be the -d switch, corrected too (destination). And one javac-command was false from me; used javac za.ac.HelloWorld.java instead of za/ac/Helloworld.java (if you aren't on Windows, then with backslashes, of course).

Comment: @userunknown: you saved my life, and i thank you for the posts and replies. Yes i found "THE -d" switch and it worked great, just as you said.

regards 

aiden

Comment: @userunknown Check original post amended. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The `-jar` option accepts a *filename*, not a *class*.

You should just do

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

But keep in mind that you need to specify a main-class in the manifest file you you want it to execute using the `-jar` option.

The manifest file should look like

```
Main-Class: za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld
```

and you include it with the `m` option on the `jar` command.

Also, it seems that you're adding the .class-file in the root of the jar file. It should be in the `za.ac.uj.csc2a` directory

---

If you don't want to go with a manifest file, you could also launch it like this (perhaps that's what you're trying):

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld
```

Comment: i Then get this

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: 
za/ac/uj/csc2a/HelloWorld)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:442)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Se

Comment: Answer updated. Also, it seems that you're adding the `.class`-file in the root of the jar file. It should be in the `za.ac.uj.csc2a` directory.

Comment: @AidenStrydom Because the `HelloWorld.class` inside the JAR file must be in the right subdirectory, not at the root directory of the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar file is named HelloWorld.jar, not za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld.jar. So obviously, java doesn't find it.

The jar file *contents* must respect the package hierarchy, so *inside* the jar file, the `HelloWorld.class` must be in the folder `za/ac/uj/csc2a`.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually call 
    java -jar HelloWorld.jar 
instead of 
    java -jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld.jar

Answer (score 0):

> place all the files in the right directories

Are you sure about that? Because if your code is in a package `za.ac.uj.csc2a` then your source file must be in a directory `za\ac\uj\csc2a`, you should compile it with a command like this:

```
javac za\ac\uj\csc2a\HelloWorld.java
```

and also inside the JAR file it should be inside a directory with that name, so you should package the JAR with a command like this:

```
jar cf HelloWorld.jar za\ac\uj\csc2a\HelloWorld.class
```

You will only be able to execute it with `java -jar` if it is an executable jar, in other words, if you add a manifest file to the JAR with a correct `Main-Class` attribute. If you didn't do this, you should be able to run it from the JAR with:

```
java -cp HelloWorld.jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld
```

See [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for details on how to package your app in an executable JAR file so that you can execute it with

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a jar called HelloWorld.jar:

```
jar cfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class
```

Then trying to invoke a different jar name (za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld.jar):

```
java -jar za.ac.uj.csc2a.HelloWorld.jar
```

They need to be consistent